# json comparison failing after springboot 2.6 +upgrade

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have upgraded my springboot from 2.4+ to 2.6 plus. after doing this, in one of my end to end test
the comparison between my actual and expected json  is failing. on inspection i found that the actual json which i'm getting as a result from running the test has extra white space inside, while all the other content and values are same.